# How to list Startup Programs

Tags: c#

For all of the startup programs in `Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run`

This code works:

```
            RegistryKey HKCU = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
            foreach (string Programs in HKCU.GetValueNames())
            {
                string GetValue = HKCU.GetValue(Programs).ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(getFilePath(GetValue)); //Environment.NewLine
            }
            HKCU.Close();
```

But for all of the startup programs in `HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\Run`

This code does not work:

```
   RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\Run");
            foreach (string Programs in key.GetValueNames())
            {
                string GetValue = key.GetValue(Programs).ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(getFilePath(GetValue));
            }
```

Please note; I have admin rights, I have a 32bit OS and also is my app settings.

Comment: What is the error you're getting ?

Comment: the second function does not list Startup Programs. it cant find the location "HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\Run"

Comment: Have you checked if this key is really present in your registry ?  Otherwise, maybe you are not allowed to access this key from your application.

Comment: @power: Is your app 32 or 64 bit and are you trying it out on a 32 or 64 bit Windows?

Comment: the key exist Ihave check it with ccleaner. @ho1 Ihave a 32 bit os and also is my app.

Comment: run you program As Administrator

Comment: Being an admin and running as administrator are two different things.

Comment: I have disabled the Windows UAC. so things should run with admin right. and i have given the admin right to my app within the manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\Run");
```

and not

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\Run");
```

HKLM is already chosen with "Registry.LocalMachine".

But by the way, my windows 7 doesn't have this key.

Comment: yes it was indeed a typing error this example.  it should be RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\Run");

Answer (score 0):

just use following...

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
```

or

```
RegistryKey keyy1 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
```